# Exception-safety: add cleaning up actions during the execution

Tags: c++, error-handling

I need to call some functions and clean up some resources acquired after those calls. I can't just call some determined `Cleanup` function in the end, because during the execution of the functions exceptions may be thrown, so the precise cleanup action depends on the point at which exception is thrown (it may be thrown in the first function, in second, ...). So I created `Cleaner` helper class, in which I register cleaning actions, specific for each function. If at some point exception is thrown, only cleanup actions that are really needed (and are correct) will be called.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using CleanupAction = std::function<void()>; 

class Cleaner
{
public:
    void AddCleanupAction(const CleanupAction &i_action)
    {
        m_cleanup_actions.push_back(i_action);
    }
    ~Cleaner()
    {
        for (auto &action : m_cleanup_actions)
            action();
    }
private:
    std::vector<CleanupAction> m_cleanup_actions;
};

struct SomethingFirstDoer
{
    static void Do()
    {
        // do something first ...
    }

    static CleanupAction GetCleanupAction()
    {
        return []()
        {
            // cleanup needed for the first action..
        };
    }
};

struct SomethingSecondDoer
{
    static void Do()
    {
        // do something second ...
    }

    static CleanupAction GetCleanupAction()
    {
        return []()
        {
            // cleanup needed for the second action..
        };
    }
};

void DoSomething(Cleaner &i_cleaner)
{
    SomethingFirstDoer::Do();
    i_cleaner.AddCleanupAction(SomethingFirstDoer::GetCleanupAction());

    SomethingSecondDoer::Do();
    i_cleaner.AddCleanupAction(SomethingSecondDoer::GetCleanupAction());
}

void DoSomethingWithCleanup()
{
    Cleaner cleaner;
    DoSomething(cleaner);
}
```

Any remarks, low-level and high-level, would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

Another version of the code: now it doesn't use the `Cleaner` class, just relay on local objects destructors.

```
#include <functional>

#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

using CleanupAction = std::function<void()>; 

struct SomethingFirstDoer
{
    static void Do()
    {
        // do something first ...
    }

    static CleanupAction GetCleanupAction()
    {
        return []()
        {
            // cleanup needed for the first action..
        };
    }
};

struct SomethingSecondDoer
{
    static void Do()
    {
        // do something second ...
    }

    static CleanupAction GetCleanupAction()
    {
        return []()
        {
            // cleanup needed for the second action..
        };
    }
};

void DoSomething()
{
    SomethingFirstDoer::Do();
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(void) {
        SomethingFirstDoer::GetCleanupAction();
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    SomethingSecondDoer::Do();
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(void) {
        SomethingSecondDoer::GetCleanupAction();
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
}
```

Comment: Can you add a `main()` that shows how to use this?  At present, it's not clear how this is more convenient to users than simple `catch` blocks to clean up, or RAII objects.

Comment: How would you recommend to use simple catch blocks, for example?

Comment: `try { action1(); try { action2(); } catch (...) { cleanup2(); throw; } } catch (...) { cleanup1(); throw; }`  It's ugly, so it would be nice to see how you improve on that.

Comment: well, we just call DoSomethingWithCleanup() (or DoSomething() for code from Update 1) in main. Sorry, maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)